# I am/have or I graduated?

Tags: grammaticality, expression-choice, present-perfect, present-tense

A girl uploads a picture on Instagram and writes-

> Yay, I am Graduated.

This sounds quite a bit odd to me.

But amongst the following, which one is more natural?

- Yay, I graduated today.
- Yay, I have graduated today.

situation: I got my graduate degree today and I am calling my friends up to say that I have finally got it.

Is “I have graduated today”, correct?

Comment: Is the girl American? What about her other posts, do they seem to be written in good English? As to your request, the first seems more spontaneous in speech. Are your friends in the US?

Comment: well, she is an indian. But I am graduated sounds a bit odd to me, whenever i hear this sentence i feel as if she has millilitre and litre markings up on her body. LOL @Mari-LouA

Comment: Well, if her dialect is Indian English I can't say whether it is correct or not. In British and American English it would be considered an error, then again, maybe it's slang in N. America. I wouldn't say  `I am graduated`

Comment: No, "I am graduated" is most definitely not slang in NA.

Comment: Instagram isn't really a repository of correct grammar, even when the poster is graduated...

Comment: @Snow Is a graduated poster skinnier at the top or bottom? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both usages exist.  There is no reason to say one of them is "incorrect".

[image: Ngram]

[LINK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20graduated%2Che%20was%20graduated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20graduated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20graduated%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: But the Ngram kinda tells you that using the auxiliary "be" with graduated is non-existant today. What about using the present tense [**he is** graduated](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+graduated%2Che+was+graduated%2C+he+is+graduated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20graduated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20graduated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20graduated%3B%2Cc0)? Is that "correct"?

Comment: No one says "I am graduated" in contemporary English. Ngrams only documents written language, not usually how people actually speak.

Comment: There are a few of us old fussbudgets, @Lambie, who still treat *to graduate*  as transitive (in the sense of *certify s.o.'s completion of a baccalaureate program),* with institution as subject and student/alumnx as object. We may even pronounce the *t* as intervocalic [t] while doing so! [;)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/424775/76878)

Comment: @Brian Donovan Is "graduated from college" good enough for you? I never have said; I graduated college [transitive], but **I graduated from college** because in fact graduated college would have another meaning. Such as scaling something. A graduated pillar.

Comment: It is idle to object to the now more common intransitive usage of the verb with student/alumnx as subject (and, yes, optional adverbial modification with the prepositional phrase *from college).* But reports of the death of the transitive usage, with student as object ("the program graduated fifty students that year") or as subject of the passive form ("I was graduated in 1977"), are greatly exaggerated--just as are reports of the death of intervocalic [t] in American spoken English, as you well pointed out, @Lambie.

Comment: @Brian Donovan But I hear the transitive more than the intransitive. The program graduated 50 students is a different usage than what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Oh, so do I, but *less* ≠ *never.* And the passive usage (with student/alumnx as subject), which is an extension of the transitive, seems to me to be precisely what OP brought up. For what it's worth, OED lists transitive usage (for the academic sense of the word) as dating from 1588, and as "now *rare* exc. *U.S."* (which is my country), and the intransitive as dating from 1807.

Answer (score 0):

I graduated today is probably the clearest in meaning.
I have graduated seem problematic since graduated is past tense.  The event is over.  You could not say you graduated prior to the event.  The verb have is present tense.  I have a college degree is present tense for instance.  I have graduated what does that mean? You can say I just graduated YAY!  THAT seems what I have graduated seems to mean in your context.

Comment: Please supply "evidence" that supports your claim. It is not enough to say "That's how I say it". EDIT: You have a problem with *I have graduated*? Interesting.

Comment: First I never said this is how I say so it must be correct.  Please reread my answer and do not assume things in someone else's words without even asking.  I explained why the sentence used was improper

Comment: The "That's how I say it" is often used by newcomers to justify an answer. I was just anticipating a possible rebuke. You explained *after* or while I was commenting.

Comment: I can't find a possible case where I would ever say I have graduated.  I would say I just graduated or I graduated college 6  years ago , etc. I don't see why HAVE should be there at all.

Comment: Ah, lassies and laddies, I have graduated from spelling bees to lexicography. [not true by the way, just an example to be obnoxious]. :)

Comment: Why not erase the HAVE?  Does the meaning change without HAVE?