# The pronunciation shift of T to D in the United States

Tags: pronunciation, flapping

I'm from the United States and I have recently discovered that I don't pronounce the T as a soft D as other Americans do. Neither do most of the people in my area or my parents. I pronounce the word "butter" like someone from most areas of Britain would, I don't pronounce it like "budder." Other than the pronunciation of this consonant, my pronunciation aligns with the main American pronunciation. I was wondering if there is some kind explanation as to why the pronunciation of the t hasn't shifted to a D in my area? I live in the Southern New Hampshire by the way.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "northeast"? New York Siddy? Rochesder? Connedicut? Bosdon?

Comment: I'm from southern New Hampshire

Comment: so anytime you hear the flap T on TV, isn't it weird to you that you speak differently from anyone else?

Comment: I really didn't notice until recently, and that was only because someone else pointed it out

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have (or have remnants of) the so-called Mid-Atlantic Accent.  https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/how-a-fake-british-accent-took-old-hollywood-by-storm

Comment: So, the way I speak is technically unnatural? This would make some amount of sense due to the fact that area I live in is called New England. Most people in my area speak without the flap T. We also tend to use some vocabulary that would be considered British, such as "posh".

Comment: By the way, the only feature I seem to have from this accent is the pronunciation of t. The rest seem to match the modern American pronunciation.